# Creating repeated predictions with a single model with distinct data frames on R

Tags: r, function, loops, prediction, confidence-interval

I hope someone can help me.

I would like to perform several predictions with one model with distinct data.

I've created 100 data frames with 60 observations sorted from another data frame as below:

```
mtz100<-replicate(100,aracaboot[sample(nrow(aracaboot), size=60, replace=T),]
```

Ok, now I want to fit 100 new models with my model with the new 100 data frames created.

After this I want to predict to raster layers.

Someone can give a start point to automate this in R?

SOLUTION:

```
RasterImgs <- list()
lenght(RasterImgs) <- 100              

 for(i in 1:100) {
     DataNew <- data[sample(1:nrow(data),60,replace=T),]
     Model <- glm(DataNew, ....)
     List <- Model
     RasterImgs[i] <- predict(list,....)
      }
```

Thanks by the Help @Señor O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you approach is a little bit off right now. Doing `sample(nrow(dataframe),60)` won't give you the desired effect because `nrow` returns ONE number (not a vector). So you want to do `sample(1:nrow(dataframe),60.....` instead.

I don't know of a better approach than using a simple `for` loop if you're sampling indices:

```
List <- list()
lenght(List) <- 100              ## Growing a list inside a loop is inefficient

for(i in 1:100) {
    DataNew <- Data[sample(1:nrow(Data),60,replace=T),]
    Model <- glm(DataNew....)
    List[i] <- Model
    }
```

Comment: Also, are you sure you want `replace=T`? That will just give you the possibility of using duplicate entries for each model.

Comment: Now I would like to use the `List[i]` to do prediction to raster layers.     `DataNew <- data[sample(1:nrow(data),60,replace=T),]
    Model <- gbm.step(DataNew, gbm.x = 1:4, gbm.y = 5, family = "poisson", tree.complexity = 2, learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.75)
    List[i] <- Model
    PrRaster <- predict (preds,List[i], n.trees= List[i]$gbm.call$best.trees, type="response") # Trying to use the fitted models to raster image prediction
}` After run the code i got this `Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list".`

Comment: It's kind of hard to read your code in comment format, but you can't apply `predict` to a list of models, you have to apply it to each element in the list:

Comment: First, thanks by the help. I'm so grateful. 
Sorry about the format, I'll be more clear. I think to use `lapply(List, predict)` outside of `for` loop . Is it right? I have tried without success. How to use?

Comment: Yes. If `predict` can be applied to the model you're using, i.e., if `predict(gbm.step(...your data / args...))` works fine, and the list contains only `gbm.step` elements, then `lapply(List, predict)` will work outside the `for` loop. I've tested this with `lm` and `glm` objects.

Comment: I've tested too with `lm` and `glm`, works fine. But, I've found my problem, `List[i] <- Model` doesn't grow a list of models from function `gbm.step`,now I'm trying to find what object, model, produced from `gbm.step` to store in `List`. I'll give news. I've learned a lot with this task and your advices.Thanks again by the help @Señor O.